# -map_metadata grab multiple audio stream metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

Right now i have a batch file to remove all metadata and then apply my preferred and only needed metadata it removes all and makes the title name the file name.

But I want it to retain the audio tracks language metadata.

```
mkdir output

for %%a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -metadata:s:a:0 language=jpn -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -c copy -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="%%~na" "output\%%~a"
```

This is for this file:

https://pastebin.com/hfSUzMPp

I would love to figure out how to automate copying all present audio stream metadata and applying it to the new bat, because as of now i have to define the languages manually and that isnt fun for large batchs of files.

I tried this:

```
mkdir output

for %%a in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -c copy -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="%%~na" "output\%%~a"

pause
```

But it causes both audio streams to be defined as Japanese.

https://pastebin.com/vwVRSc75

Rather than correctly being audio stream number 1 being Japanese and the 2nd being English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of options matters. When there are multiple instances of the same option (with or without the same specifiers), the ones of the left are applied first.

`ffmpeg -i "%%a" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map_metadata:g -1 -c copy -metadata title="%%~na" "output\%%~a"`

Comment: How would I go about doing it for videos with more than 2 audio tracks is their a universal way of making it so any and all audio tracks metadata is retained? I have some that have 2 to even 6 different audio streams. Or would defining each one be the only option?

Comment: Modified command.